# Displaying a specific post in a wp query by post id

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm simply trying to display a specific post id from my custom post type 'homepage_video'. I'm sure that this is the correct code but it seems to be returning all of the posts rather than just Post Id 40.

```
<?php
                    query_posts('post_id=40&post_type=homepage_video');
                    while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                        <div id="video-panel-blue">
                            <?php get_custom_field('home-video-iframe', TRUE); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: See here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175746/42702

Answer (score 9):

`post_id` is not a valid argument for `query_post` Change `post_id` to `p`,
so you get:

```
query_posts('p=40&post_type=homepage_video');
while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div id="video-panel-blue">
    <?php get_custom_field('home-video-iframe', TRUE); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

to see the list of arguments you can use with query_posts take a look at [this codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: what is `get_custom_field` ?

Answer (score 2):

All posts, regardless of their post type, are stored in the same table in WordPress. That implies that the post ID is unique. So you don't have to use `query_posts()` to get a specific post, you can simply use `get_post()`:

```
$my_post = get_post(40);
echo $my_post->post_title;
```

Comment: What if instead of post_title, I wanted to get a field?